# Problem with parsing xml file

Tags: android, xml-parsing

I have this website i need to parse for an android app.

http://www.wow-coupons.com/rss_online_coupons.xml

I am using the code AndroidXml from the below site to parse

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/x-android/index.html?ca=dgr-lnxw82Android-XML&S_TACT=105AGX59&S_CMP=grlnxw82

There are no syntax errors in the xml file. Other websites work for the same code.

If there is a connection problem, how do I resolve it?
Please help.

Thanks,
Siri

Comment: show us what have you done so far.

Comment: The same code works for other websites I am trying to parse. I wanted to know where I should look to debug the problem with the website I am mentioned in the question above. Siri

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just tested your feed with the BuzzBox SDK demo app and it is parsed fine.

See http://hub.buzzbox.com/android-sdk/demoapp

You can get the SDK and integrate it in your App.
Or you can rewrite the parser. The SDK is using
`org.xml.sax.XMLReader` and `javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser`